# Webdriver/ Exception using grid and Safari: Error forwarding the new session

Tags: macos, selenium, webdriver

I use `selenium-server-srandalone-2.35.0.jar`.

In the server side, I run the next command: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role hub -port 4951`

and with the next configuration:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
capability.setBrowserName("safari");
capability.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.MAC);
WebDriver webdriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4951/wd/hub"), capability);
```

In the MAC computer, I run the next command: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role node -hub http://myIP:4951/grid/register`

When I try to connect (in the new RemoteWebDriver...), It gives me the next excpetion:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=MAC, browserName=safari, version=}
Command duration or timeout: 720 milliseconds
```

I try to find the reason, but without success. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar -role wd -hub http://myIP:4951/grid/register -browser browserName=safari,platform=MAC
```

If it doesn't work, maybe you have to set a new capability (safari path):

```
capability.setCapability(SafariDriver.DATA_DIR_CAPABILITY,
         "/Users/<your_user>/Library/Safari");
```

That works for me.